# const char pointer C++ to Python swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have the following function which I call in Python to encode some data:

```
EncodeDataToAudioBuffer(const char *stringToEncode, int32_t size, int32_t type, const char *AudioTrackString, int32_t AudioTrackSize, void *Object);
```

I understand that from the following error SWIG wasn't able to map the const char so I have tried to map this for the argument but haven't managed to win.

```
TypeError: in method 'EncodeDataToAudioBuffer', argument 4 of type 'char const *'
```

I've tried to map and apply my own type maps:

```
    %module SDK
    
    %include "stdint.i"
    
    %{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    #include "api.h"
    %}
    
    %include "numpy.i"
    
    %init %{
    import_array();
    %}
    
    
    %numpy_typemaps(audioBuffer, NPY_CFLOAT, int)
    
    %apply (audioBuffer* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(audioBuffer* data, unsigned int size)};
    
   %typemap(in) (const char* AudioTrackString) (Const char* melodyString, Py_ssize_t length) %{
  if(PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input,&AudioTrackString,&length) == -1)
    SWIG_fail;
  $1 = (const char*)AudioTrackString;
%}
    
    %include "api.h"
    
    %inline %{
    PyObject* PyDecodeAudioBuffer (PyObject* obj, int size, void *Object) {
      const int dtype_obj = PyArray_ObjectType(obj, NPY_FLOAT);
      PyArrayObject* arr = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_FROM_OTF(obj, dtype_obj, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
      float* float_ptr = (float*) PyArray_BYTES(arr);
      int32_t result = DecodeAudioBuffer(float_ptr, size, Object);
      PyObject* result_py = PyLong_FromLong(result);
      return Py_None; */
      return result_py;
    }
    
    PyObject* PyGetDecodedData (void *Object) {
      char stringDecoded[10];
      PyObject* result_py = PyLong_FromLong(result);
      PyObject* result_decoded = PyUnicode_FromString(stringDecoded);
      PyObject* result_tuple = PyTuple_New(2);
      PyTuple_SetItem(result_tuple, 0, result_py);
      PyTuple_SetItem(result_tuple, 1, result_decoded);
      return result_tuple;
    }
    %}
```

Comment: Did you try changing python side to use byte or c side to use wchar_t?

Comment: Where do you call or otherwise use `EncodeDataToAudioBuffer`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I call and use this from python when I try and send the encoded string

Comment: @vish I tried byte from the python side the first char const doesn't give any issues surprises me

Comment: @JJohn sorry, could not understand your comment above. Does that mean if you changed to 'byte' on python side, you _dont_ have issue anymore?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve], including the code where you actually call the function. Then also copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question.